# Replacing matched groups differently using ECMAScript (Conditional Replace)

Tags: regex, ecmascript-6

I want to rename some files using PowerRename using regex.

My files look like this:

`hidded_this_should_not_be_hidden`

I want the output to be:

`this should not be hidden`

So I need to match both `hidden_` and replace that with nothing, and globally match every occurrence of `_`, and replace that with  .

It was easy using PCRE2. My expression was `hidden_|(_)` and my substitution `${1:+ :}`. But I simply could not find the equivalent in ECMAScript. Is there any? Every solution I have seen so far requires you to use a function for your substitution, while I can only use pure ECMAScript.

Comment: No, there is no conditional replacement pattern support in ECMAScript.

Comment: Functions are pure ECMAScript?

Comment: So `input.replace(/^hidden_/, '').replace(/_/g, ' ')`?

Comment: @Bergi Yeah, that one's possible, but I had hoped for a solution with just a single replace. That would be a bit more efficient, now it needs to rename every file twice.

Comment: Why not just [`s.replace(/hidden_|_/g,' ').trim();`](https://tio.run/##LYzNDsIgDIDvewpuQKLsamJ8lgahGZhKF1p32rvjFj1/P6@4RUm9rnrdbmMkbqJGzMPYUnPGBlqqgBT@UIbGCk@EH7H3aSJU0/HUJXRcKSZ08z/cYV4u1lgftNe384d@3pkwEC/uyPwYXw) ... anoter option to use a callback like [`s.replace(/(hidden)?_/g, (m0,m1) => m1?'':' ');`](https://tio.run/##JY3LDoMgEEX3fsXsBhKrdde0sX4KoTARGh6Gof4@1bg@99zz1btmU/xWb/ujNZMTV2CYAZ23lpKqzrNil3/BqpSr@pC6CL66LlCFQuech0Jb0IbEKC4uFzWuPYh47@MkYX5DnBbEJwLKQz1LOdAQ8iqOC9naHw) but it's probably less efficient.

Comment: @bobblebubble I'm not using JavaScript, just Microsoft's own renaming tool that happens to use ECMAScript for batch renaming files. I can only enter the expression and the substitution, then it will perform the action on all files.

Comment: You do not have to use the tool. In Windows, you can use a Powershell script to rename files and there, you can implement this logic. Or, just keep replacing twice, it may be a much simpler operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ECMAScript standard does not allow conditional replacement patterns.

See [*22.1.3.18.1 GetSubstitution ( matched, str, position, captures, namedCaptures, replacementTemplate )*](https://262.ecma-international.org/13.0/#sec-getsubstitution) that describes all possible substitution patterns, and the conditional replacement pattern is not on the list of available options.

Keep replacing twice:

1. Replace `hidden_` with an empty string and
2. Replace `_` with  .